# only getting last object in a forEach function on an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, event-listener

I'm trying to loop through an array I made everytime I click on dynamically created html, and I'm using a forEach function to loop through it. My problem is that only the last object is being shown in the forEach function in the array and none of the other values in the array are showing. Here is my function to do this -

```
// //handler to show text from eventData array
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    let noEvents = document.getElementsByClassName('no-Events')[0];
    let eventsDescContainer = document.querySelector('.events');

    if(e.target.classList.contains('day')){
        [...eventData['events']].forEach((event)=>{
            if(event['day']===e.target.innerHTML && event['month']===headerMonths.innerHTML && event['year']===headerYears.innerHTML){


            //the event['day'], event['month'], and event['year'] values are not looping through the array, they are only showing whatever the last object values I added to the eventData array

                //show event Text
                showEventText(event['description'], event['month'], event['year'], event['day']);

            }  else {
                console.log(e.target.innerHTML + event['day']);
                console.log(headerMonths.innerHTML + event['month'])
                console.log(headerYears.innerHTML + event['year']);
                console.log(eventData['events']);
                clearEventText(headerYears.innerHTML);
                noEvents.style.display='initial';
                noEvents.innerHTML = `There are no events on ${headerMonths.innerHTML} ${e.target.innerHTML} ${headerYears.innerHTML}`;

                //reverse flexDirection to original direction
                eventsDescContainer.style.flexDirection = 'column';
            }
        });
    }
});



//JSON event data


let eventData = {
    "events": [
        {
            "description": 'es',
            "year": '2018',
            "month": 'Nov',
            "day": '28'
        }
    ]
 };
```

It loops through the eventData array, but if I add another object to the eventData array and I try to loop through it in my eventListener, the eventListener will only get the item that I just added to the array, which is the last object in the array, and it won't loop through the rest of the array to get the older objects.

the event['day'], event['month'], and event['year'] values are not looping through the array, they are only showing whatever the last object values I added to the eventData array

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

EDIT:

this is the function I'm using to add new Objects to the eventData array

```
 //adds json to eventData
function newEventJson(description, month, year, day){
let event = {
    "description": description,
    "year": year,
    "month": month,
    "day": day
 };
 eventData.events.push(event);
```

}

when I use console.log to debug this in my eventListener, the eventData['events'] shows all the values in the array, but the event['day], event['month'], and event['year'] all stay the same values as the last item in the eventData array.

Here is a link to a codepen of it https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/ZmJByP .

Comment: `...eventData['events']` is an array with only 1 item which is an object. If you would add another array to `eventData` using the same key `events`, you run into trouble. Basicly you're not creating unique indexes for `eventData`. It would make more sense to add more objects to the existing `events` index than trying to add more arrays with the same index name.

Comment: Never mind, that's probably not making much sense either. Edit your question and show uw how a modified array looks like and how you're modifying it. As it stands, your question is just too unclear.

Comment: Alright so it's because it only gets the [...eventData['events']] when I call it once? I'll put it in a seperate function then and see if that works..

Comment: As I said, edit your question with the info requested. You're saying: "It works, but when I do this, it doesn't". Yet you're not showing us what it is that you're doing. Just explaining it.

Comment: I'm using a different eventListener to add new events to the array. This eventListener is only to show the events if they exist. I'm not sure what you mean by 'It would make more sense to add more objects to the existing events index than trying to add more arrays with the same index name.'

Comment: As I said, that didn't make much sense because I didn't have the information I needed. It seems like `...eventData['events']` is an array and each element contains an object. You've used `event` as a name for the current array item (the object) which is just confusing as hell, even though it makes sense cause you're talking about events here (event is normally a JS event).

Comment: I'd start with adding `console.log([...eventData['events']].length);` right above the `forEach` loop and see what that returns. If it only returns 1 after you've added something to that array, the issue rests in the array and not your loop. If it shows 2 or more, the issue lies within the loop.

Comment: The length increases when I add new objects to eventData array, but even knowing this I still don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: You can't expect to magically solve an issue without tracing the issue down first. Proper debugging helps both you and us to know where to look. To find an issue, you search step by step. Is the array properly added? Now we know it is. Next step is to find out why it doesn't loop both of them. Or does it loop them both, but you just don't see it? Next step: Right above your foreach loop, add `let counter = 0;` Then inside your loop: `counter++;` Then outside your loop underneath it: `console.log(counter);`. See what that returns and you know how many times it looped. Is it really just 1 loop?

Comment: Btw, this is also why you should avoid `forEach` loops and use `for` loops instead. A for loop is performance wise a lot faster than foreach and much easier to debug. Foreach loops also come with many other downsides like the inability to break the loop and it ignores any modification to the array index while looping it.